# File Pointer is not working in C even though i have the txt file in the same directory

Tags: c

File Pointer is not working in C even though i have the txt file in the same directory 
Long story short I just want to scan and print out the files from a txt file but i can't seem to do so

```
#include <math.h> 
#include <stdio.h>
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS    //to avoid scanf warning or error

int main(void)
{
    int  id;
    FILE *ptr;

    ptr = fopen("records.txt", "r");
    fscanf("%d",&id);
    printf("%d", id);
    fclose(ptr);
}
```

Comment: "File Pointer is not working..." - what does that mean?

Comment: needs error checking on fopen

Comment: "//to avoid scanf warning or error" um... so you don't want to know when scanf messes up?

Comment: @ant  The program just crashes when i try to run it

Comment: fscanf requires a FILE * as a parameter to work properly. Change it to fscanf(ptr, "%d", &id);

Comment: The first parameter of `fscanf` must be a file.

Comment: Also check the return value from `fscanf()` which should be `1`. Why are you disabling warnings? You really do need them, evidence this question.

Comment: I'm only getting 1 value from my records.txt

Comment: yes because you are reading only once. You can add loop to get whole content.

Comment: @DaveySwaveyRonny, you're only *asking* for one value from the file.

Comment: that's because you're reading just one number. Go look up how the scanf type of functions work.

Comment: Seeing the faults commented - is the one number the *right* number? I doubt it.

Comment: Yeah I am receiving the right number. I'ma go ahead and include the while loop BRB

Answer (score 2):

The `fscanf` has three parameters.
Like this :

```
//fscanf('YOUR FILE Pointer HERE', "%d",&id);
fscanf(ptr,"%d",&id);
```

If you are using any *Nix OS then run `man -s3 fscanf` in terminal to get to know more about `fscanf`.
You can replace `fscanf` with any other library function to check it's documentation.